# How to define a namespace inside an ASP.NET page (inline code method)?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, namespaces, inline-code

I insert the below code inside an ASPX file (MyTest.aspx). I don't want to use `Code Behind`.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    namespace MyNamespace
    {
        class MyClass
        {
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
```

But the following error occurred while browsing the page (MyTest.aspx):

`Compiler Error Message: CS1519: Invalid token 'namespace' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

**How to define a namespace inside an ASP.NET page (inline code method)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's obvious that `asp.net` won't allow it but have you tried an indirect way:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>    
<script runat="server">
    class MyNamespace.MyClass
    {

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Write("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
```